# Android application to disable application notifications that doesn't need root

Tags: android, notification

I am looking for an Android application that:

- can disable application notifications, either by clicking on a notification or by listing all installed applications and allowing the user to check which application he allows/disallows to push notifications.
- doesn't need root

Going through the usual path is too time-consuming:

[image]

The application [Notifications Off](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.aboutmycode.NotificationsOff) needs root:

[image]

Comment: I suspect there's a reason why the app you mentioned requires root. That is because the function you require, which controls the behaviour of the Android system itself, is probably a superuser function. So I strongly suspect that any app that does this is going to require superuser (root) permissions. So I reccomend that you either root your device (although there are certain risks with that.), or you just use the normal method. Sure, it's time consuming, but you only have to do it one time per application. Unless you regularly switch notifications on and off for certain applications?

Comment: If you are willing to pay a developer you could probably create a service that auto dismisses certain application notifications when they arrive.  This is a nasty hack but probably should work.  I have rudimentary understanding of Android which is why I'm guessing its possible in at least version 7.0